# Populate data in range worksheet to comboBox and TextBox in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to populate the data of the range in column A into the ComboBox form and the data of column B into the TextBox form using VBA Excel, so that when selecting a value in the ComboBox the value in the TextBox also changes.

[image]

I try like the code bellow

```
Private Sub cboProdi_Change()
    TextBox1.Value = Range.Cells(Rows, 2)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cboProdi.List = [Lookup!A2:A39].Value
End Sub
```

When running it displays a Compile error:

> Argument not optional

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify on which row you receive the error ... I suppose `Rows` is throwing it.

You could read both columns to the list of cboProdi - and set bound column to 2.

Then you can read this value in the cboProdi_Change event.

```vb
Private Sub cboProdi_Change()
TextBox1.Value = cboProdi.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With cboProdi
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "100;0"
    .BoundColumn = 2
End With

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lookup")
With ws.UsedRange
    cboProdi.List = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 2).Value
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Private Sub cboProdi_Change()
    TextBox1.Value = cboProdi.List(cboProdi.ListIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Range   As Range
    Dim Cell    As Variant
    
    Set Range = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A39")
    
    For Each Cell In Range.Cells
        cboProdi.AddItem Cell.Value
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Populate Text Box Depending on Combo Box Selection

```vb
Private Sub cboProdi_Change()
    
    Dim nrg As Range: Set nrg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup").Range("A2:A39")
    Dim krg As Range: Set krg = nrg.EntireRow.Columns("B")

    Dim Kode As Variant:
    
    With Application
        Kode = .Index(krg, .Match(cboProdi.Value, nrg, 0))
    End With

    If IsError(Kode) Then
        TextBox1.Value = "Not available"
    Else
        TextBox1.Value = Kode
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cboProdi.List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup").Range("A2:A39").Value
    'cboProdi.ListIndex = 0 ' to show the first item in the combo box
    cboProdi_Change ' to populate 'kode' in the text box
End Sub
```

- You could also simplify:

```vb
Private Sub cboProdi_Change()
    
    Dim rIndex As Long: rIndex = cboProdi.ListIndex + 1
    
    If rIndex = 0 Then
        TextBox1.Value = "No selection"
    Else
        TextBox1.Value = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookup").Range("B2:B39") _
            .Cells(rIndex).Value)
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Note that this will allow for duplicates in column `kode`.